# Using pandas in VS code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I just can't get pandas to work. I have installed it correctly (I think), but everytime I write the "import pandas as pd" it turns into this:

1    Import pandas asdef yourFunction(x):

2       return x*x

3

4    #df is your dataframe

5    #example function is applicable for all INT dataframe

6. df squared = df.apply(yourFunction)

Advice, help please

Comment: Your image is showing code that is clearly wrong. Also, don't post images of code ;) See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/)

Comment: please upload your code as text instead of an image. that being said, change your first line to `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Your image show a function def smeared into your import statement. Why did you think that was ok?

Comment: I know the code being shown is wrong. I am trying to ask if anyone knows why it turns into that, after I write "import pandas as pd" on the first line.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem you repeated. If it's not a code issue, could you upload a simple gif to demonstrate the error?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your image is missing some content and does not wrap.

```
import pandas as pd

def yourFunction(x):
    return x*x
```